# openGl object disappears at certain zCoord

Tags: c++, opengl

I have cube , which i'm trying to move using glTranslatef() function . Everything works great , except that cubeb start disappearing at z>1.

Here is my code

```
void owidget::initializeGL()
{   
    glDepthRange(0,100);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glOrtho(-5.0,5.0,-5.0,5.0,-500.0,500.0);
}

void owidget::paintGL()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(xPos/100,yPos/100,zPos/100);
        glRotatef(xRot,1,0,0);
        glRotatef(yRot,0,1,0);
        glRotatef(zRot,0,0,1);
        cube(0.3);
    glPopMatrix(); //Fuction for dislpaying cube
}

void owidget::resizeGL(int width, int height)
{
    glViewport(0,0,width,height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
}
```

[Here is a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzNnF.png)

Comment: Remember that after everything gets transformed into the final projection matrix, things are SUPPOSED to disappear when they are z>1 or z<-1. Sorry if you already knew this, but it wasn't clear from the question if you did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your setup is a little weird. You're setting `zFar` in `gluPerspective` correctly in initializeGL, but it's getting overwritten by `glLoadIdentity` in paintGL, which resets `zFar` to the default, which is 1 in [Normalized Device Coordinates](http://learnopengl.com/#!Getting-started/Coordinate-Systems).

If you change `glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);` to `glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);`, this should work.

I would also recommend defaulting `glMatrixMode` to `GL_MODELVIEW`. By this I mean that whenever you're done editing the projection matrix, call `glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);`

```
void owidget::initializeGL()
{   
    glDepthRange(0,100);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    gluPerspective(0,650/600,20.0,100.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}

void owidget::paintGL()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(xPos/100,yPos/100,zPos/100);
        glRotatef(xRot,1,0,0);
        glRotatef(yRot,0,1,0);
        glRotatef(zRot,0,0,1);
        cube(0.3);
    glPopMatrix(); //Fuction for dislpaying cube
}

void owidget::resizeGL(int width, int height)
{
    glViewport(0,0,width,height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}
```